# Python string encode

Tags: python, string, encode, python-2.x

I have this code

```
att=att.replace("à","a")
```

but I received this error...

```
  att=att.replace("à","a")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I fix?

Comment: You can decode them. `att=att.decode('utf-8').replace("à".decode('utf-8'),"a")`

Answer (score 3):

Don't mix unicode with byte strings.
Python2 does implicit conversion, but Python3 does not. Even if you are not using Python3, it is good practice to avoid mixing the two.

In Python2, if `att` is a unicode, then

```
att.replace("à","a")
```

will *implicitly* try to *decode* `"à"` and `"a"`to be unicode as well before attempting to replace `"à"` in `att`.
Python2 uses `ascii` (by default) to do the implicit decoding.

`"à".decode('ascii')` raises `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`.

To fix this error, since `att` is `unicode`, `att.replace`'s arguments should be unicode as well:

```
att.replace(u"à",u"a")
```